# I want to add the character after every occurrence of a pattern in a string to an arraylist of characters

Tags: java, arraylist, character

My goal is to get the character after the given pattern added into the array list. My issue is that with this code I get an error with i. It exceeds the length of text.

```
public static ArrayList<Character> getCharsThatFollowPattern (String text, String pattern)
    {
    ArrayList<Character> charAfterPattern = new ArrayList<Character>();
    int patternLength = pattern.length();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < text.length())
    {
        charAfterPattern.add(text.charAt(text.indexOf(pattern, i) + patternLength));
        i = i + text.indexOf(pattern, i) + patternLength;
    }
    return charAfterPattern;
}
```

Comment: What is the error you get? BTW, if you step through your code in your debugger, you'll probably figure it out yourself.

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do? It is very usual to deal with `ArrayList<Character>` when a simple `String` (or at worst a `StringBuilder`) does basically the same thing.

Comment: I get the IndexOutOfBoundsException: string index out of range:7

Comment: I'm trying to add all the characters after every occurrence of the pattern. For example, if I have text = "abcabdabe" and the pattern is "ab" it should return ['c','d','e']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see three main issues with your code.

The first two are related to the way `indexOf()` operates.

- It returns `-1` when the pattern is not found. You do not allow for this case and hence process some parts of the string twice.
- It returns the index relative to the *start* of the string, even if you search from some place other than the start. Hence you should not do `i = i + text.indexOf(...`, but rather `i = text.indexOf(...`.

The third issue is that you do not properly handle the case where the pattern is at the end of the text, ie. there is no next character.

Here's my rough solution based on yours:

```
public static List<Character> getCharsThatFollowPattern (String text, String pattern)
{
    List<Character> charAfterPattern = new ArrayList<Character>();
    int patternLength = pattern.length();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < text.length())
    {
        int index;
        if ((index = text.indexOf(pattern, i)) < 0) // Check pattern is present
            break;
        i = index + patternLength;
        if (i < text.length()) // Check there is a next character
        {
            charAfterPattern.add(text.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return charAfterPattern;
}
```

Basic tests:

```
("abc", "ab")       => [ 'c' ]
("abcabdabe", "ab") => [ 'c', 'd', 'e' ]
("abcabdab", "ab")  => [ 'c', 'd' ]
("ababdab", "ab")   => [ 'a', 'd' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution using a more appropriate return type of `String`:

```
public static String getCharsThatFollowPattern(String text, String pattern) {
    return text.replaceAll(".*?" + pattern + "(.)(.(?!" + pattern + "))*", "$1");
}
```

If you desperately, absolutely must have a `List<Character>`, turn the above into that type:

```
public static List<Character> getCharsThatFollowPattern(String text, String pattern) {
    return text.replaceAll(".*?" + pattern + "(.)(.(?!" + pattern + "))*", "$1")
        .chars().mapToObj(i -> (char) i).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Note also that you should always use the most abstract type for method APIs, ie `List<Character>` not `ArrayList<Character>`. See [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: With both of your methods and my original example it still only returns ['b'] instead of ['b','b']. It is for school so it does need to be an ArrayList

Comment: Sorry not my original example. The test that I need it to pass is "abababa", "aba" and it returns ['b','b']

Comment: @evan are you sure it should return ['b']? In other words, is it required that you *reuse* input when matching?

Comment: Yes. so the second a in the string "abababa" counts as the end and beginning of a pattern.

Comment: Then I would use a `Matcher`